# Javascript Incompatibility with IE and FF (call function)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, incompatibility

i was writing some code in javascript and i need it to work on most browsers but it only works in googleChrome, IE and FF dont call this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  showLocation(<?php print "\"$citta2\""?>,<?php print "\"$row[nome] $row[cognome]\""?>,<?php print "\"$row[id]\""?>); return false;
  </script>
```

(i know that it doest call it because the 1st thing that its suppoed to do is make an allert) do u know of any reason why that would work only in chrome? if you need the all file i can post it below but its a bit long, also I'm positive that the problem is in that call.

edit1: here is showLocation code:

```
function showLocation(address2,nomi0,id0) {
            alert("1");
    var nomi1 = nomi0;
    var id1 = id0;
    geocoder.getLocations(address1, function (response) {

        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
        {
            alert("Errore con il primo indirizzo");
        }
        else
        {
            location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
            geocoder.getLocations(address2, function (response) 
            {
                if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                {
                    alert("Errore con il secondo indirizzo");
                }
                else
                {
                    location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                    calculateDistance(nomi1,id1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

(it uses google maps api to get latitude and longitude of a city)

Comment: show us showLocation() code, probably got a syntax error...

Comment: If some JavaScript doesn't work, then show us the JavaScript, not PHP that outputs JavaScript.

Comment: … and show us a complete test case that demonstrates the problem. If you "know that it doest call it because the 1st thing that its suppoed to do is make an allert", then include a version of `showLocation` that only does that. A [live test case](http://jsbin.com) would also be helpful.

Comment: added the code for showLocation

Comment: Can you post the error message which you get in IE/FF..?

Comment: I dont get an error message, i get a blank page, i dont even get alert("1"); that is the 1st thing that that function is supposed to do (was testing where the problem was)

Comment: not an answer but for the print you could use `showLocation(<?php print "'{$citta2}','{$row[nome]} {$row[cognome]}','{$row[id]}'"?>);` to make things easier to read.

Comment: I just tried making an other call to a function that only has an allert, (no parameters in input) and it still didnt work

Comment: Use `echo json_encode($citta2)` instead of wrapping the raw string in quotes, as you did in `"<?php echo $citta2; ?>"`. Let existing libraries escape data instead of doing it (poorly) yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not an answer(as of yet) just need more than the 600 characters allowed in comments.

First, lets make your script tag a little easier to read, and add some debugging:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        if (window.showLocation)
        {
            showLocation(<?php print "'{$citta2}','{$row[nome]} {$row[cognome]}','{$row[id]}'"; ?>);
        }
        else
        {
            // if you see this message:
            // then you have a syntax error before or within the creation of showLocation
            alert("showLocation has not been created!");
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("Error from caller: " + e);
    }
</script>
```

And now in your other code, add some debugging:

```
function showLocation(address2,nomi0,id0) {
    try {
        alert("1");
        var nomi1 = nomi0;
        var id1 = id0;
        geocoder.getLocations(address1, function (response)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                {
                    alert("Errore con il primo indirizzo");
                }
                else
                {
                    location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                    geocoder.getLocations(address2, function (response) 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                            {
                                alert("Errore con il secondo indirizzo");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                                calculateDistance(nomi1,id1);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (e)
                        {
                            alert("Error in callback#2: "+ e);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert("Error in callback#1: " + e);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("Error in functon: " + e);
    }
}
```

_Added *even more* debug alerts_

Comment: adding try and catch in the call of the function makes it not work in chrome as well(function doest get called and no error is posted, taking out the try and catch from call only makes it work in chrome and the function works correctly (no alert for the error)

Comment: I have also tried to make a function test(){alert("test");} and calling it midway in my page with test(); and again works only in chrome

Comment: Im thinking you have an exception being throw before `showLocation` is is created and that's why it's not being called(it doesn't exist)

Comment: new code works in chrome with no errors, and doesnt produce anything in firefox, no errors no results, no alerts, no nothing =[

Comment: That would be most helpful :)

Comment: actually, it works now, i might have been using a cached version of the page... idk but ur code works =] Thanks a ton!!!